# Can't scroll ListView when child expands height

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a `ListView.builder` that renders a list of Containers who can expand in height when the user clicks on it ( I'm using AnimatedSize to wrap the Containers), however I noticed that when the Container is expanded I can't scroll the ListView by pressing and dragging around the expanded area, only in the area that Container occupied originally.

```dart
 ListView.builder(
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: profilesList.profilesCount,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ProfileBar(
                              id: profilesList.profiles[index].id!,
                              index: index,
                              name: profilesList.profiles[index].name,
                              emoji: profilesList.profiles[index].emoji,
                              gender: profilesList.profiles[index].gender,
                              color: profilesList.profiles[index].color,
                              height: profilesList.profiles[index].height,
                              birthday: profilesList.profiles[index].birthday,
                              isSelected: profilesList.selectedProfileID ==
                                  profilesList.profiles[index].id,
                              onSelect: (_) async {
                                profilesList.selectProfile(
                                    profilesList.profiles[index].id!);
                                    Provider.of<GoalModel>(context, listen: false).getGoal(profilesList.profiles[index].id!);
                                await UserSettings.setProfile(
                                    profilesList.profiles[index].id!);
                                _getRecords(context);
                              });
                        },
                      ),
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap that `Listview` with `SingleChildScrollView` and add `physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to `Listview` and check.

Answer (score 0):

So I found my problem is that my list item had a `GridView` widget, I changed the physics to NeverScroll and fixed it.